# GRUB 2 stops dual booting Windows 8

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, grub2

I own a laptop with two hard disks. Windows 8.1 is installed in UEFI mode on the first disk, and I recently installed Gentoo on the second one. Now I want to be able to select the OS on boot in GRUB2 menu. I followed the instructions listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting) and everything seems to be configured correctly for the dual boot. Here is the custom menu entry in `40_custom`:

```
# Win8.1 uefi boot x64
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "efi" ]; then
        menuentry "Microsoft Windows 8.1 UEFI-GPT" {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod fat
                insmod search_fs_uuid
                insmod chain
                search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 7CEB-5B77
                chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
        }
fi
```

But when I boot the laptop and select the "Windows 8.1" entry, GRUB2 prints the following error:

```
error: no such device: 7CEB-5B77.
error: file `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.

Press any key to continue...
```

It then returns to the boot menu.

I also noticed that it is possible to boot Windows from GRUB menu once:

1. Set the Windows Boot Manager over GRUB in BIOS
2. Boot Windows
3. Restart
4. Set GRUB over Windows Boot Manager in BIOS
5. Now when I select Windows in GRUB menu, it will boot properly. Next time the described error will raise again.

I'm not a Linux/GRUB expert at all, but it seems that GRUB can't find the right partition by the fs_uuid, although it is present in the `blkid` output and is found when running `grub2-probe`. What can be the reason for this?

Here's the `blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Wiederherstellung" UUID="044AE97A4AE9693E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="549b8c2d-7c9a-45b4-8de2-e4177da085ea"
/dev/sda2: UUID="7CEB-5B77" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="602df980-fad8-4375-9662-ab5008396e00"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a566edcb-d2e7-4c6d-b824-5cb67c2f05b3"
/dev/sda4: UUID="EE62F0D762F0A58D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="345362da-33c0-4040-8d0a-43bc50662901"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="grub" PARTUUID="5665be3f-7674-4715-9aec-99ab2bba1714"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="19DB-9111" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="boot" PARTUUID="6c5313e9-04f8-433f-bbf2-32cb76b4ca2e"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="4dbfa06a-d6c9-4031-9420-cda2645cac1e" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="swap" PARTUUID="74ff4304-59c6-4c53-a70b-9eec171200f1"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="669905f0-995d-44cd-b7c6-4cc5bc2ac268" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="rootfs" PARTUUID="c5160cc6-486c-422b-b7f7-159188e7fabd"
```

Comment: Try BootRepair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to build BootRepair for Gentoo. Also, according to [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/256274), boot-repair is equivalent to `grub2-mkconfig` which does not mention any problems when executed.